# Adding Data Source to SSRS Report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am writing a report and instead of using connection to server, I was given data source to use. I want to know how to add the data source to the report.

Edited: I have tried to add through the shared data sets, but I have been asked to deploy the developed report first so, I am little confused

Comment: Ask the person that told you that. Only they can clarify the method they want you to use. There are multiple ways (embedded data sources, shared, data connections, connection strings, etc...)[see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/data-connections-data-sources-and-connection-strings-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: If you've used the shared data source when designing your report, then provided that shared data source is already deployed then the deployed report will make use of it.

Comment: I have to give connection string and credentials

Comment: What do you mean by "I was given data source to use"?  Like they physically sent you the db files for use on your local machine?

Comment: Either you were given an `rds` file (shared datasource), in which case add it to your report project and use it in your reports. Or you were given a connection string, in which case create a new shared datasource and use it in your reports.

Comment: @steve-o169 no they didnot physically give me one. I was told there was datasource created that I can use.

Comment: @DaleBurrell a datasource was created, but I was told to give connection string and credentials to use it. How do I go about this then?

Comment: If they expect you to connect via connection string and credentials, you would have to get that information directly from them.  There's no way to really guess the connection string.  Where I work, I need to connect to a VPN for one of the many servers we use before I can access the dbs.  Perhaps you need to do the same?

Comment: @Steve-o169 I ask them for connection string